# How to add validation in a login page in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new and can't seem to find a way to properly add validation to my login form. All I could do is add required so that it won't call the api when the fields are empty. I would also like to add email validation that it should contain '@' and password validation for like 6 characters and numbers and symbols. I tried following some tutorials but they seem way too complicated and I can't seem to find a way to call the performLogin function along with the validation functions using the tutorials. This is the [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/validating-a-login-form-with-react) that I was following by the way.

I tried this in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-lumiere-oc7o9) so far, can someone please show where to add the validations exactly?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";

function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      <Link color="inherit" href="">
        Hello
      </Link>{" "}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {"."}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
  },
  form: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)
  }
}));

export default function Login(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const performLogin = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    var body = {
      password: password,
      email: email
    };

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    const url = "/api/authenticate";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const text = await response.text();

      if (text === "redirect") {
        props.history.push(`/editor`);
      } else if (text === "verifyemail") {
        props.history.push(`/verifyOtp/${this.state.email}`);
      } else {
        console.log("login failed");
        window.alert("login failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={performLogin}>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />

          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              {/* <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link> */}
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="/register" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={8}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

the problem is that most tutorials/guides won't show exactly where to call the login function and just do some console logging in handleSubmit and I'm really confused there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to validate things in the `performLogin` method, prior to setting the `body` variable, then error out if it's not valid.  So you can do the following:

Add a variable to track the error state:

```
const [error, setError] = useState("");
```

Add this to `performLogin` right before `var body = {...}`

```
//Validate Password
if(email.indexOf("@") <= 0){
  setError("Email address must contain an @.");
  return; //don't log in
}
else{
  setError(null);   //no error
}
```

Then display the error in your view if there is one.  Add this right before the `<form...>` in your render method:

```
{error && 
   <div style={{color: "red"}}>
     <span>{error}</span>
   </div>
 }
```

If I forked it right, this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-noyce-wtq0q) should show the changes.

This is just a basic example for performing the validation in a very simple way.  For more advanced, involved validation, I'd break it out into a separate function, or even a separate component (e.g. EmailInput).  But this should give you enough to keep moving forward.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it's working for me now. also I've checked formik and tried this https://codesandbox.io/s/validated-react-form-i2bii. could you tell me why handlesubmit and values aren't recognized at line 10 and 11 in ValidatedLoginForm.js

Comment: using your answer, I created this simple validation form and it seems to be working fine https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-jackson-8c481